# Remove last row in a locked subform

Tags: ms-access

I am pretty new to access so sorry that this is a low level question.  I have a form with a couple subforms on it and one of the subforms is locked for editing.  That subform is just used to see values associated with a field in the main form.  The problem is, in that subform it shows the last row (where you usually add info for a new row) as filled in for a couple fields and blank in others.  I assume this is a product of it being locked.  Is there a way not to show the Last part where you enter new information since I'm not going to be adding info there anyways?  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change propery `Allow Additions` on Data tab of subform to No